# Confused in selecting the encryption method for mobile number and email encryption

Tags: encryption, decryption

I'm new in cryptography and I'm developing a mobile app that gets `user_name`, `E-mail ID`, and `mobile number` as input. I'm a bit confused about how to encrypt that data so that I can decrypt it later.

- Which is the secure way of encryption so that I can transmit the data to the server for storing. Suggest me some way on how to encrypt and send those data in encrypted form.

Comment: Apple, welcome to Cryptography.SE. In cryptography, you will notice that later, the details are important, as we say like the devil in details. Since you want to transmit it to the server, the first question is, what kind of operations are going to perform on the stored data on the database ( that is an assumption here). Does each client has a public-private key? Are there any thread of a non registered user can send data? etc...

Comment: @kelalaka Hi, I have no idea on what to select between the Asymmetric and Symmetric method for my encryption things. The operation will be like For example the user mobile number and user_name can be accessed by other users but not the email ID. And there will be no thread for non-registered users for sending the data. Only registered users can send data. CRUD operation will be done in the database.

Comment: You can edit your question to clarify.

Comment: This is a near duplicate of a question asked in Sec.SE.